# Is it true that binaries generated by visual studio don't have any symbols?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, symbol-tables

All output the same:

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols
```

This is what I find after several experiment with `objdump`,is this true?

If that's the case,I want to give it a little further: is it true all binaries under windows don't have symbols?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio default settings put debug symbols into a separate file with a .pdb extension.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659754/the-gs-g-option-equivalent-to-vs2010-cl-compiler/4662345#4662345) by @metamatt which explains the other debug formats you can get by changing compiler options.

Comment: is it true that by default binaries generated by visual studio don't have any symbols?

Comment: @compile-fan: The answer is more complicated than "yes" or "no". There are (by default) no symbols in the executable, but there are symbols corresponding to the executable and stored in a .pdb file.